# Can't get enum to convert to json properly using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an enum:

```
public enum Animal 
{ 
    Dog, 
    Cat, 
    BlackBear 
}
```

I need to send it to a third-party API. This API requires that the enum values I send be lower case and occasionally require underscores. In general, the names they require don't match the enum naming convention I use.

Using the example provided at https://gooddevbaddev.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/deserializing-c-enums-using-json-net/, I tried to use a custom JsonConverter:

```
public class AnimalConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var animal = (Animal)value;
        switch (animal)
        {
            case Animal.Dog:
            {
                writer.WriteValue("dog");
                break;
            }
            case Animal.Cat:
            {
                writer.WriteValue("cat");
                break;
            }
            case Animal.BlackBear:
            {
                writer.WriteValue("black_bear");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var enumString = (string)reader.Value;
        Animal? animal = null;
        switch (enumString)
        {
            case "cat":
            {
                animal = Animal.Cat;
                break;
            }
            case "dog":
            {
                animal = Animal.Dog;
                break;
            }
            case "black_bear":
            {
                animal = Animal.BlackBear;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

Back in the properties of a class, I put the attributes on the Animal as so:

```
[JsonProperty("animal")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(AnimalConverter))]
public Animal ZooAnimals { get; set; }
```

When I run the program though, it seems to completely ignore the JsonConverter and rather than seeing expected values like "black_bear" or "dog", I see "BlackBear" and "Dog".  How can I get the JsonConverter to actually do the conversion from the name of the enum value to the string I specify to replace that value with?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete program, like for instance for [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) that demonstrates the problem? I wrote a small LINQPad program to test and it uses the converter here.

Comment: You refer to `Animal` and `Animals` in your code sample; can you clarify these both refer to your enumeration? For what it's worth, I managed to get your code working using the following snippet:
`Zoo zoo = new Zoo { ZooAnimals = Animal.Cat }; string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zoo);`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You don't need to write your own converter. Json.NET's [`StringEnumConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) will read the [`EnumMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute.aspx) attribute. If you change your `enum` to this, it will serialize from and to the values you want.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Animals 
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "dog")]
    Dog, 
    [EnumMember(Value = "cat")]
    Cat, 
    [EnumMember(Value = "black_bear")]
    BlackBear 
}
```

(As a minor note, since `Animals` isn't a flags enum, it [should be singular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx): `Animal`. You should consider changing it to this.)

Comment: Hi Tim, how can i use EnumMember in .Net 2.0?

Comment: @RickyJiao I think I'd create my own converter, based on `StringEnumConverter` ([see source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs)), and make it work with my own `EnumMemberAttribute` class, based on `EnumMemberAttribute` (just needs the one property and constructor).

Comment: Do you know why the `StringEnumConverter` uses `EnumMember` and not the Json.NET `JsonProperty`? Because I use `JsonProperty` everywhere else, but appareantly doesn't work with enums..

Comment: @Kapé I can't say that I really do; it does seem odd for it to use a built-in type instead of a custom one, as is usually done elsewhere. Here's my guess: Enum members do not represent properties (i.e. the key in the key/value pair), but values, so it doesn't make sense to use `JsonProperty` to describe it.

Comment: Seems like you need to give the enum the DataContract attribute for EnumMember to work, since the above here didn't work for me. Like this
`[DataContract]
public enum Animals....`

Comment: Perfect solution. Worked for me!

Comment: Doesn't work with parameter bindings. GET api/animals/black_bear/children isn't working.

Comment: This is not System.Net.JSON but Newtonsoft.JSON. This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Might return null, better to use try catch
public static Animals GetEnum(string val)
{
    return (Animals)Enum.Parse(typeof(Animals), val, true);
}

public static string GetName(Animals an)
{
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(Animals), an);
}

public static string GetReplace(Animals an)
{
    var get = GetName(an);
    var tempstr = "";
    int getch = 0;
    foreach (var chr in get.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (chr == chr.ToUpper())
        {
            getch++;
            // Second up value char
            if (getch == 2)
            {
                tempstr += "_" + chr;
            }
            else
            {
                tempstr += chr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
             tempstr += chr;
        }
    }
    return tempstr;
}
```

Comment: Can't use that since the name of the enum value must occasionally change. For example, given an enum value of "BlackBear", it must convert to show a value of "black_bear".

Comment: @Xaniff `GetEnum(val.Replace("_", "").Replace(" ", ""));` And see the edited, use this function: `GetReplace(animal);`

Comment: @Xaniff If you can't use the uppervalues, Make the final string `GetReplace(animal).ToLower()'

Comment: I guess I'm really looking for a more generalized solution so I can specify via an attribute what value I want returned for the enum rather than have to write a conversion like this every time (especially seeing as the third-party API is rather inconsistent in their naming rules). But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ConConvert()` implementation is not correct.
It should be:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return objectType == typeof(Animals);
}
```

Comment: Tried flipping that from string to Animals and it still returns "BlackBear" rather than "black_bear". But thanks!