# C# - Web API - Serializing Enums as strings with spaces

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, enums

My question is simple, but a little more specific than other questions related to serializing enumerated types as strings.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public enum MyEnum
{
    TypeOne,
    TypeTwo,
    TypeThree
}

public class Foo
{
   [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
   public MyEnum Types { get; set; }
}
```

When the Web API controller sends serialized Foo objects, they may look something like this:

```
{
    "Type" : "TypeTwo"
}
```

**My Question:** is it possible to send serialized enums as strings with spaces before each capital letter? Such a solution would produce JSON like this:

```
{
    "Type" : "Type Two"
}
```

Let me know if there's any additional information needed to solve my problem. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

It's preferable if the enums are only converted to strings with spaces while serializing them to *JSON*. I'd like to exclude spaces while using `MyEnum.ToString()` on the backend.

Comment: Does adding an EnumMemberAttribute `[EnumMember("Type Two")]` do anything?  The source for StringEnumConverter on github appears to take advantage of it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you think using that attribute will have an effect on each `MyEnum.ToString()` method?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try adding EnumMember as shown below,

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Type One")]
    TypeOne,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Type Two")]
    TypeTwo,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Type Three")]
    TypeThree
}
```

You may need to install a package called System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives from Microsoft to use that.

Comment: This works! And to clarify my edit, this will _only_ effect JSON serialization. Thank you!

Comment: this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19768223/530933) might also be helpful.  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] at the top of the enum