# Get error when deserializing a string to object defined in *.proto?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, json-deserialization, proto

Please notice that the object is defined in proto file, not in a common cs file. It has different behavior.

I'm using c#. Part of my proto file is:

```
    message CodeDependency {
        string path = 1;
        DependencyType type = 2;

        enum DependencyType {
            NONE = 0;
            TAR = 1;
            ZIP = 2;
            TAR_GZ = 3;
            DIRECTORY = 4;
        }
    }
```

And I have a json string:

```
{"codeDependency": {
                    "path": "/CAP_TEST/job_manager/modules/1c8185d5-2add-4bd4-a332-8b21a6819608/tmpr9z7xinh.tar.gz",
                    "type": "TAR_GZ"
                }}
```

I've tried three ways to deserialize it:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CodeDependency>
CodeDependency.Parser.ParseFrom
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<CodeDependency>
```

None of them works. From the error message, it seems that 'TAR_GZ' can't be deserialized.

```
Error converting value "TAR_GZ" to type 'Microsoft.ABC.GRPC.Modules.Module+Types+CodeDependency+Types+DependencyType'. Path 'graph.nodes[4].module.codeDependency.type', line 273, position 21. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'TAR_GZ' was not found
```

If I change 'TAR_GZ' to 'TAR', it's ok. So maybe the problem is related to the underline in 'TAR_GZ'? Is there any way to solve it in C#? (It's ok in python.)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try NewtonsoftJson: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: @MaxMustermann he already has

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get enum to convert to json properly using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767863/cant-get-enum-to-convert-to-json-properly-using-json-net)

Comment: What do you get if you *serialize* the protobuf message that contains the data you want? (To JSON)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've tried (Newtonsoft.Json)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. The problem is: For class(and enum) defined in common cs file, it works fine. But for class defined in *.proto(and compiled to cs by protobuf dll), it doesn't work. The error message is "Error converting value "TAR_GZ" to type 'Microsoft.ABC.GRPC.Modules.Module+Types+CodeDependency+Types+DependencyType'. Path 'graph.nodes[4].module.codeDependency.type', line 273, position 21. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'TAR_GZ' was not found"

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried your problem with NewtonsoftJson and an Root-Object, that worked for me
here my solution:

```
    namespace RegexTests
{
    static class StringExtension
    {
        public static T DeserializeJson<T>(this string toSerialize)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(toSerialize, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
        }
    }

    class Root
    {
        public CodeDependency CodeDependency { get; set; }
    }

    class CodeDependency
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public DependencyType Type { get; set; }
    }

    enum DependencyType
    {
        NONE = 0,
        TAR = 1,
        ZIP = 2,
        TAR_GZ = 3,
        DIRECTORY = 4,
    }

    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"CodeDependency\": { \"Path\": \"/CAP_TEST/job_manager/modules/1c8185d5-2add-4bd4-a332-8b21a6819608/tmpr9z7xinh.tar.gz\", \"Type\": \"TAR_GZ\" } }";


            var obj = json.DeserializeJson<Root>();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I've tried JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. For class(and enum) defined in common cs file, it works fine. But for class defined in *.proto(and compiled to cs by protobuf dll), it doesn't work